# Rename + Move Nested Files in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a directory `users` which is full of folders named for each user. Within those folders, there is a file called `userinfo.csv` which I would like to pull out of the folder and into the `users`. Since every file in the user folder is called userInfo, I want to rename it to include the username which is in the folder. I tried the following but it doesn't work because the username in `$dir` is the full directory. I'm not that attached to renaming it to the username, I just need to rename it something so that when it moves into `users` I won't be left with just one file and a bunch of errors.

How can I improve this?

```
# for every subdirectory, copy userinfo.csv to /users and rename to avoid confusion/errors
for dir in /path/to/users/*/; do
    (
        cd "$dir" && cp userinfo.csv _$("dir").csv && cp _$("dir").csv /path/to/users/
    )
done
```

Comment: That specific error suggests that the editor you wrote the script in added Windows-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: good catch, thank you. though even once I fix that, it still doesn't do what I want. I've edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Is the location of the `userinfo.csv` file identical relative to each user? Is it always `/path/to/users/*/userinfo.csv` or it can be at any depth under the `/path/to/users/` folder?

Comment: What do you think `$("dir")` does?

Comment: @deimos yes it will always be `/path/to/users/*/userinfo.csv` and @choroba I now realize that $("dir") is the full directory so of course renaming it as such wouldn't have worked.

Comment: `$("dir")` is a *command substitution* that will attempt to execute `"dir"` and return its output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the username in the final filename, would

```
for i in /path/to/users/*/userinfo.csv ; do
  mv $i /path/to/users/userinfo-$RANDOM.csv
done
```

do the trick for your use-case ?

If not, you can also use bash's parameter substitution:

```
for i in /path/to/users/*/userinfo.csv ; do
  mv $i /path/to/users/${i//\/-}
done
```

This will replace all `/` with `-` in the variable `$i` (path+filename).
So you'll end up with, for example:

```
/path/to/users/path-to-users-john-userinfo.csv
/path/to/users/path-to-users-jack-userinfo.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(ls -1 /path/to/users/); do
    mv /path/to/users/$i/*/userinfo.csv /path/to/users/userinfo_$i.csv
done
```

This will work assuming the `userinfo.csv` location is `/path/to/users/$user/userinfo.csv`. In cases when `/path/to/users/` contains folders with no `userinfo.csv` or just files, `mv` won't do anything and therefore can be ignored.

The `$i` in this case will contain the name of each item in `/path/to/users/` be it a file or a folder.

Comment: [Bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)